# Does Apple MapKit have a unique identifier like Google Places does?

Tags: ios, mapkit, google-places-api, apple-maps

I've looked through Apple's documentation and can't find if Apple Maps (i.e. MapKit) offers a unique ID similar to what Google offers with the Places SDK - https://developers.google.com/places/ios-sdk/place-id

I've reviewed all the MapKit documentation and can't find anything.

Why am I asking this?  I'm building an app that will allow users to save/bookmark 'places'.  I need a way of being able to retrieve that place's details using the unique ID so that I can retrieve its info again.  At the moment it seems like my best option is to use the Google Places SDK as this will allow me to search and find a place, saving the place ID in my database and then use the same place ID to look it up again later.

Comment: `CLPlacemark` can be serialized and deserialized.. so you can store it with whatever id you want then retrieve it by id and deserialize it. With Google Places SDK, you will need to pay monthly just to use it.. Also.. according to Google SDK Documentation: `These results may or may not include the original place. The request is chargeable.`

So you're not guaranteed anything anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can initiate a [Place Search](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search) in the Places SDK using a name, address, or phone number to retrieve the Place ID, which you can then use as planned. This allows you to store a name or address and use that for lookup. Your other option is to go native and use [CLPlacemark](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/clplacemark), which can be initialized using a CLLocation and stored/retrieved. Here's a helpful article on [native geocoding](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/converting_between_coordinates_and_user-friendly_place_names)

Comment: Thanks.  Wouldn't I just store the Place ID?  And that way I can always retrieve it that way.  I'm thinking that because the name could be updated or there could be similar results based on the name alone.

Comment: If you use the Google SDK from the start then yes, you can store the Place ID directly and use it to look up details about the location. If your app has a native iOS map which you want to use in conjunction with Google's API, you'll initially be starting out with a CLLocation (or other iOS parameter) which you'll have to convert over to Google's SDK

Comment: Does Apple store universally-unique CLLocation's as part of their Apple Maps service? If not, then must every developer make a new CLLocation over-and-over again for the same popular location on a map, unique to their app context?

Answer (score 0):

It's 2024 and I've been suffering from the same thing for a few days now. After bunch of digging, I couldn't find any accessible unique ids for places on Apple Maps, simply Apple decided to keep it private.

So, I needed to generate a unique id for each place, send it to my database, and making sure that when a user selects the same place again, the same id will be generated.

Bottom line: it's all about how to generate the id while maintaining the criteria above

My solution was to generate the id based on the place name and the geocoded address of the place, using Apple's built-in CLGeocoder:

```
private func generatePlaceIdentifierBasedOnLocationAndName(_ location: CLLocation, _ name: String, completion: @escaping (_ id: String?) -> Void) {
    let geoCoder = CLGeocoder()
    geoCoder.reverseGeocodeLocation(location, completionHandler: { placemarks, error in
        guard error == nil, let placemark = placemarks?.first else {
            completion(nil)
            return
        }
        var id: String = name
        if let countryCode = placemark.isoCountryCode {
            id += "-\(countryCode)"
        }
        if let state = placemark.administrativeArea {
            id += "-\(state)"
        }
        if let city = placemark.locality {
            id += "-\(city)"
        }
        if let street = placemark.thoroughfare {
            id += "-\(street)"
        }
        if let additionalStreetInfo = placemark.subThoroughfare {
            id += "-\(additionalStreetInfo)"
        }
        completion(id)
    })
}
```

Be aware that there may be some problems if Apple changed the place name/location on Apple Maps, or even changed the geocoded address info, eg. street name changed, but this is unlikely, so happy coding!